# What update for a void recursion function

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

Hi I want to use recursion to find the leftmost value in the last row of the binary tree.

I try to do it in this way:

```
class Solution {

public:
    int findBottomLeftValue(TreeNode* root) {
        int lmValue = root -> val;
        int Maxdepth = 0;
        Maxdepth = helper(root, 0, Maxdepth, lmValue);
        cout << Maxdepth;
        return lmValue;

    }

private:
    int helper(TreeNode* root, int depth, int Maxdepth, int lmValue) {
        if (!root) 
            return depth;

        int leftDepth = helper(root -> left, depth + 1, Maxdepth, lmValue);
        int rightDepth = helper(root -> right, depth + 1, Maxdepth, lmValue);

        int curDepth = max(leftDepth, rightDepth);
        if (curDepth > Maxdepth) {
            Maxdepth = curDepth;
            lmValue = root -> val;
        }

        return Maxdepth;

    }
};
```

The depth can be updated because I return it. However, the lmValue cannot be updated. So the answer is wrong.

I found a solution which do in this way:

```
class Solution {
public:
    void findBottomLeftValue(TreeNode* root, int& maxDepth, int& leftVal, int depth) {
        if (root == NULL) {
            return;
        }
        //Go to the left and right of each node 
        findBottomLeftValue(root->left, maxDepth, leftVal, depth+1);
        findBottomLeftValue(root->right, maxDepth, leftVal, depth+1);

        //Update leftVal and maxDepth
        if (depth > maxDepth) {
            maxDepth = depth;
            leftVal = root->val;
        }
    }

    //Entry function
    int findBottomLeftValue(TreeNode* root) {
        int maxDepth = 0;
        //Initialize leftVal with root's value to cover the edge case with single node
        int leftVal = root->val;
        findBottomLeftValue(root, maxDepth, leftVal, 0);
        return leftVal;
    }
};
```

What I lost here is that the solution doesn't return anything, but every variable get updated at each recursion level.

Is that mean if I return nothing, I return everything?

As a newbie, please give me some instructions.

Appreciate!

Comment: No, you're actually not returning anything. You're mutating your data structure. Do you have any experience working with mutable data structures?

Comment: Sorry, I just have some basic knowledge of C++, and I know the meaning of mutable data structure, however I have no experience about it. But I don't know why am I mutating my data structure, could you please give me some ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Oh I realize that the second Solution use reference for the leftval and maxDepth. But I change my own first Solution from int lmValue to int &lmValue, lmValue still not get updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very broad question, but I'll do my best to give you a summary.

```
void findBottomLeftValue(TreeNode* root, int& maxDepth, int& leftVal, int depth) {
    // (Recursive calls removed, not relevant to this discussion...)
    if (depth > maxDepth) {
        maxDepth = depth;
        leftVal = root->val;
    }
}
```

The `&` in front of the type means you're passing the variable by reference. The variables `maxDepth` and `leftVal` are not being copied into the function, so assignments to those variables will be reflected in the original values. This is a common idiom in pre-C++11 code to return multiple values from functions. Here's a simpler example.

```
void by_value(int x) {
    x++;
}
void by_reference(int& x) {
    x++;
}
int main() {
    int var = 0;
    cout << var << endl; // Prints 0
    by_value(var);
    cout << var << endl; // Prints 0, since the value was copied to the function
    by_reference(var);
    cout << var << endl; // Prints 1, since the value was passed by reference
                         // so the changes in the function are reflected in the
                         // caller
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I realized this problem. Could you please take a one more look at my own first Solution code, because when I just change int lmValue to reference int &lmValue, the original value still not get assigned.

Comment: Have you verified that the if statement in your code (which does the `lmValue` assignment) is actually executing? There doesn't seem to be anything immediately wrong that I can see.

Comment: It seems that in your first solution, when your recursion unwinds to the top (i.e. the first call to the helper function), curDepth will always be larger than Maxdepth and lmValue will always be set to root->val which at the top of the recursion is the value at the root of your tree.

If it helps, I would walk through some example trees to see what your code is doing (you can add that to your original post) and I think you'll see the problem.

Comment: Thank you guys so much, after use debugger, I found actually my own Solution has logic error as jjaguayo said, and the second code is already a very concise solution. After doing this problem and with you guys kind helps, I have a deeper understand about c++ logic and recursion. Appreciate!